# use aws instance connect without port 22 open from anywhere

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Right now I can connect to my ec2 instance using aws instance connect (via the browser, aws console site), if I have in my security group port 22 open from anywhere,

I tried to specify instead of `0.0.0.0/0` for port 22, the value of `ip_prefix` for my region from here:
https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

but that didn't help, I can only connect when 22 is open from anywhere.

Comment: Did you check what _actual_ IP address your OS shows you as being connected from?

Comment: Assuming the AWS feature works via SSH (which is probably safe to assume given that it requires port 22), either the `who` command or looking at your system logs (e.g. `journalctl -n 1000` or `journalctl -t sshd`) would be a good start.

Comment: ok, I saw the IP, when connecting, it's not the one I was specifying, and in that JSON there's actually lots of items with the same region value, I wonder how Amazon intended for this instance connect feature to be used

Comment: found in the json 1 item with service name: EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT, and for the region it has my region, and the ip matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to look in the json: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json
for the ip with `EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT` service name and the `region` same as mine, and I've added this ip to my security group rules (port 22)